# Собрать jar включив в него внешние файлы

Tags: java, jar, build

Доброго времени суток,

Я пытаюсь собрать jar архив, но при его запуске вылетает исключение при  обращении к файлу.

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/view/mainView.fxml"));
```

Очевидно при сборке артефакта нужно указать и этот файл, подскажите как.

Структура проекта:

[image: структура проекта]

Comment: чем собираете проект?

Comment: в idea просто добавляю артефакт и указываю Main класс

Comment: ручками добавить? или написать ant-скрипт?

Comment: ant скрипт если можно

Comment: А нельзя просто в resources его добавить? fxml и css не место в src. После обращайтесь по "classpath:/view/MainView.fxml"

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в регистре, файл у тебя называется с большой буквы, а который ты пытаешься вызвать с маленькой, поэтому он и не находит файл

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/view/MainView.fxml"));
```

Comment: Как ни странно, проблема не в этом. При запуске из ide все работает.

Comment: @Arashigor Дело в том, что idea игнорирует регист и читает, но когда ты запускаешь jar, идёт считывание через jre, а вот она уже не игнорирует

Comment: Я исправил, но при запуске jar файла все равно java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.

Comment: @Arashigor Попробуй так       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/src/view/MainView.fxml"));

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу с помощью maven'a добавив в pom.xml

```
   <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                <include>**/*.css</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

и maven-assembly-plugin

```
 <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>    
                   <manifest>
                       <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
            ...
 </plugin>
```